# Clarification about RxJS way of handling errors: "The observable data type disallows the exception from leaking from the stream's context"

Tags: functional-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I am in reference to the ***RxJS in action*** book by Manning publisher which gives the following sample code to demonstrate the RxJS way of handling errors:

```
const computeHalf = x => Math.floor(x / 2);

Rx.Observable.of(2,4,5,8,10)
   .map(num => {
      if(num % 2 !== 0) {
        throw new Error(`Unexpected odd number: ${num}`); //#A
      }
      return num;
   })
   .map(computeHalf)
   .subscribe(
       function next(val) {
          console.log(val);
       },
       function error(err) {
          console.log(`Caught: ${err}`); //#B
       },
       function complete() {
          console.log('All done!');
       }
    );
```

The book goes on to say about RxJS:

> errors don't escape the observable pipeline.

and also puts it differently:

> The observable data type disallows the exception from leaking from the stream's context.

Can someone please explain how this differs (as far as side-effects are concerned) from handling errors with a traditional `try/catch` as follows?

```
try {
 someDangerousFunction();
}
catch(error){
 console.log(error.message);
}
```

How the latter sample causes a side-effect compared to the former?

What is meant by the two quotes above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that when you set an error handler when calling `subscribe(.., error => ...)` the exception is only passed to the error handler and nothing else (you threw an exception but it was caught by RxJS).

That's what is meant by *"errors don't escape the observable pipeline."* and by *"leaking"* I think they mean the same.

In the example you posted you're throwing an error inside `map()` which is caught by `map()` automatically and sent as an error notification.

So you don't typically wrap Observable chains with `try/catch`. One important thing to notice is that if your `subscribe` call doesn't set and error handler than the error is rethrown which might break your application. In such case you might want to use `try/catch` but it's always easier to use the error handler instead.

Comment: Thanks @martin. Can you please when throwing an exception is indeed considered a side-effect?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so since the exception is transformed into an error notification and exist only in Observable chain (unless you don't have an error handler and it's rethrown). It's also usually the only way to create error notifications in operators such as `map`, `filter` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is meant to be contrasted with `Promise` and not so much with `try/catch`.  When coding against `Promise` a common error would be...

```
doSomeAsyncTask().then(rsp => {
  doSomeOtherAsyncTask(rsp).then(rsp2 => {
    myButton.label = rsp2.text;
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

One might think that they are catching errors but if some error is thrown by `doSomeOtherAsyncTask` it wouldn't actually propagate.  Of course, there are ways to avoid this but it is a pretty easy error to make if you are new to promises.